# Debugging heroku 500 server error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, internal-server-error

So this is what I get from looking at my production.logs from heroku:

```
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 50.3ms)

  Processing by EventsController#show as HTML

  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}

Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
```

Everything works locally and I have even pushed the database to heroku using db:push. Is there any more robust logging for heroku than the lines above that aren't helpful?

Comment: do you get errors when you visit the page that does not require database connection? try `heroku rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure its because you haven't ran `rake db:migrate`

If that does not work make sure that all the gems you need are in your `Gem file`, i.e. you are not making any local `require` statements to gems not in the `Gemfile`.

What I have found helpful is tailing the log.

And then you need to run this in console:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Now click on the same page you were getting problems at before and check out the logs.

EDIT: on rails 4 you'll need to add the [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem to get the detailed logs.

Comment: The actual problem I discovered was in the fact that I had accidentally made a foreign key even_id into a string instead of an integer and postgre didn't like that at all. That being said however I did discover it after upgrading to the expanded logging addon so your advice was spot on

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem.  I need the foreign key to be a string and I was wondering how you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to ruby but it might be good information for other googlers.

My issue not being able to see the actual error was that I was using a third party PHP tool that did this: `@ mysql_connect( ... )` which simply hides the error that that function didn't exist .. really evil code